# Creating a grid in Fourier-space

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I have a code which creates a square image with dimensions 4x4 arcsec running from -2 arcsec to +2 arcsec and is created on an 80x80 grid. To this I want to add another image.
This second image is created through a FFT of an 80x80 grid and thus starts out in Fourier space. After the FFT, I want the image to have exactly the same dimensions in real space as the first image.

Because Fourier space represents the scales and the wavenumber is defined as k = 2pi/x (although in this case the numpy.fft uses the definition where I think k = 1/x), I thought the largest scale would have to have the smallest k-value and the smallest scale the largest k-value.

So if x_max = 2 (the dimensions in the x-direction of the first image) and dim_x = 80 (the number of columns in the grid):

k_x,max = 1/(2*x_max/dim_x)

k_x,min = 1/(2*x_max)

and let the grid in Fourier-space run from k_x,min to k_x,max (same for the y-direction)

I hope I explained this clearly enough, but I haven't been able to find any confirmation or explanation for this in the literature about FFT's and would really like to know if this correct.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This is not correct. The k-space values will range from `-N/2*omega_0` to `(N-1)/2*omega_0`, where `omega_0` is the inverse of the sample length, given by `2*pi/(max(x)-min(x))` and N is the number of samples. So for your case you get something along the lines of this:

```
N = len(x)
dx = x[-1]-x[0]
k = np.linspace(-N*pi/dx, (N+1)*pi/dx, N)
```